# MS Graph Filter people based on userPrincipleName

Tags: azure, get, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the MS Graph API and would like to filter people returned by:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/people?
```

By the userPrincipleName, but when I try:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/people?$filter=endsWith(userPrincipalName,'outlook.com')
```

I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
        "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes."
    }
}
```

What should the query look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you do an eq by filter you get a better error message eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain/people?$filter=userPrincipalName+eq+'blah'
```

> ```
> "error": {
>    "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
>    "message": "The property 'userPrincipalName' does not support >filtering."
> ```
>
> }

It's recommend to use the Search Endpoint rather the the people endpoint as in the future that's what should improve https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-person